# Does Population estimates in American Community Survey 5-Year Data (2009-2017) includes international migration as well?

Tags: us-census, census

Does Population estimates in American Community Survey 5-Year Data (2009-2017) includes international migration as well? or is it based on residence status.

Comment: are you looking for the `migsp` variable in the [one year](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/tech_docs/pums/data_dict/PUMS_Data_Dictionary_2017.pdf)  and [five year](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/tech_docs/pums/data_dict/PUMS_Data_Dictionary_2013-2017.pdf) files ?

Comment: working on **HC01_EST_VC03** variable in 5 year ACS file

Comment: Can you the table number you are looking through? My impression is that `HC01_EST_VC03` is a column position for a given table, but does not uniquely identify a specific item within a specific table. I have a few other questions as well based on my initial search, did you do the search using American FactFinder and came across table S0701?

Answer (score 1):

The American Community Survey data are based on residents. So yes, if persons migrated to the U.S. and now live here, then they are part of the estimated population.

Also, not sure if you meant "citizen" rather than "resident" in your question. But the Census Bureau counts all people who reside in the U.S. regardless of their citizenship status. Annual estimates, which use the Decennial Census counts as part of the process, are estimates of the resident population, regardless of citizenship status.

The methodology used for the estimates depends on the geography, but you can see the methodology here:
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/technical-documentation/methodology.html